# Why is grep printing when there is no match?

Tags: bash, grep

```
$ ps ax | grep 6557
#=> 6582 s003  S+     0:00.01 grep 6557
```

But checking quickly with activity monitor there is no process with a pid 6557. And everything online says grep should return 0 when there is no match.

Comment: When you do this, ps lists all processes, including the grep command, therefore, it matches itself.  It should match once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the match:

```
$ ps ax | grep 6557
6582 s003  S+     0:00.01 grep 6557
                               ^^^^ (found it!)
```

`grep` is checking everything in the line, including the command and arguments, and `6557` is the argument you gave `grep`, so it finds its own process.

A stricter regex can fix this particular case:  `^` indicates the start of the line, and `\ \*` matches any number of leading spaces, so this will only find matches at the very beginning of the line:

```
$ ps ax | grep ^\ \*6557
```

Comment: The output of `ps ax` usually starts with a space.

Comment: @choroba so it does. (and it's not guaranteed to be just one.)  `^\ \*6557` is a bit less readable.